# unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Tags: magento-1, error, conflict

I had a helper class conflict with two of my modules. I have resolved this issue by doing following:

```
if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Amasty_Methods')) {
    class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp extends Amasty_Methods_Helper_Payment_Data {}
}  
else {
    class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp extends Mage_Payment_Helper_Data {}
}

class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data extends Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp {
}
    /**
     * Retrieve all payment methods
     *
     * @param mixed $store
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPaymentMethods($store = null)
    {
        $_methods = parent::getPaymentMethods($store);

        if (isset($_methods['sagepaysuite'])) {
            unset($_methods['sagepaysuite']);
        }
        return $_methods;
    }
}
```

Now, I get the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in /domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Helper/Payment/Data.php on line 26

Do I just delete the `public` from my function? Also what are the consequences of doing so?

Comment: Mention Magento version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the closing curly bracket after class `Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data extends Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp {
}`

Deleting the `}` solved my issue.

Now, it works fine with the `Public` declarations in the function.

Sorry to bother you all.

Comment: Finally found the right answer to accept ? :P

Comment: hahaha does that matter? :D :D I failed posting this question so I thought I cheer myself up with accepting my own question haha

Comment: I leave week me week you? :D

Comment: Haha . Yep. Its OK. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is one `}` to much ... replace

```
class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data extends Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp {
}
```

with

```
class Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data extends Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Helper_Payment_Data_Temp {
```

Comment: Yes, just realised that! Sorry to bother you. I posted the answer almost at the same time. I clearly can't see properly...

Comment: My turn for the accepted answer :D